# Read only cluster for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is there any ways to make read only cluster in Elasticsearch?

I have a very heady indexing and I want to separate the search or other activities from that.I search for Index alias,tribe node...but I couldn't come up with the idea.

Answer (score 1):

See [this section of the guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) where it says `index.blocks.read_only`: `Set to true to have the index read only, false to allow writes and metadata changes.`

Comment: I think this settings is for the index that won't have any more writes.I have a index that need indexing and reading.

Comment: I don't understand. You want it read-only, but to allow indexing?

Comment: I want sort of master/slave replication, so one is for indexing and one is for reading.